# std::vector::erase vs "swap and pop"

Tags: c++, performance, vector, erase

The "normal" way of deleting an element from a vector goes like this:

```
vec.erase(vec.begin() + index);
```

But in theory it's faster just to do this:

```
if (vec.size() > 1)
{
    std::iter_swap(vec.begin() + index, vec.end() - 1);
    vec.pop_back();
}
else
{
    vec.clear();
}
```

Is there any reason to not use the latter?

Comment: You need the normal way if you need to preserve order.

Comment: If you need deletion to be fast, you can always consider using a linked list.

Comment: @CompuChip That'll end up slower than the second example, though, and linked lists are basically slow-by-default.

Comment: @CompuChip But linked lists have numerous problems of their own. The biggest issue is the cost associated with traversing the nodes, which can result is several cache misses (or even worse, segfaults) along the way.

Comment: @user112513312 true, just pointing out that if you _really_ need a data structure with guaranteed constant-time complexity, it exists. I agree that in general (i.e. before measuring performance and figuring out that the moves resulting from deleting from a vector are the bottleneck), `vector` is the most sensible default.

Comment: I know this is an old question but its worth saying: Swap and pop is a great way to give a nice performance uptick to unordered vectors. Especially for large vectors when random access is needed. Just keep in mind that changes to the container can invalidate iterators and pointers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The second case does not preserve the order of the elements in the vector.  If this is a sorted vector or the order is important then you have just broken that in the second case where the first case would leave the order intact.

Comment: And if the order is not important then a vector was probably not the right tool for whatever the job is. Though there are some cases where order is _so_ unimportant that a vector is the right tool the job :D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `vector` is a reasonable tool when "order of insertion" is the operative ordering, rather "ordered by property"

Comment: @Caleth Agreed, but then you still have a desired order ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit no you don't, the most recently inserted element is now somewhere in the middle of the container

Comment: @Caleth The most recently inserted element is exactly where you put it, presumably deliberately and for some reason. I don't really follow what you're saying?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `std::vector<int> v; v.push_back(1); v.push_back(2); v.push_back(3); v.push_back(4); fake_erase(v, 1);` Now `v` is { 1, 4, 3 }, not { 1, 3, 4 }

Comment: @Caleth: What is `fake_erase`? Sorry, I really don't know what point you're trying to make, or how it relates to this answer/my comment.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit A method wrapping OP's `iter_swap + pop_back`. The insertion order of those elements is 1, 2, 3, 4. After removing the second element (2), the order is then 1, 4, 3. This has not preserved the order of insertion, which would be 1, 3, 4

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I believe `fake_erase` is the erase the OP is proposing.  Caleth is saying if the vector of `{1,2,3,4}` is passed to that and `2` is erased then you'd get back `{1,4,3}` which does not preserve the "order of insertion"

Comment: @NathanOliver Then I'm confused as to what part of my original comment is being disagreed with!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Me too.  I guess they were just pointing out that if you need the order of insertion then vector is the right tool for the job, which doesn't disagree with your original comment at all.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Eh? What is the difference between 'not important' and 'so unimportant'? If I just iterate elements of a vector and don't care about the order, vector is _the_ right tool for the job.